# How to import js files dynamically at compile time as input for browserify?

Tags: javascript, npm, browserify

In our project structure we have a directory containing a number of `js` files. We may add or remove any of these files later. Currently there is a `main.js` in which we import each file and create a map (file name as the key and the class 
defined in the file as the value).

**Example:**

**Validator1.js**

```
class Validator1 {
    constructor() {
        this.payRegex = /^[0-9][0-9][0-9]\/[A-Z,0-9][A-Z,0-9]*$/;
    }
    validate(obj) {
        //do something
    }
}

export default Validator1;
```

**In main.js**

```
import Validator1 from 'validator1.js';

import NoopValidator from './noop.js';

var validatorMap = {};
validatorMap['validator1'] = new Validator1;

validatorMap['DEFAULT'] = new NoopValidator;
```

We give this file to browserify to create a `bundle.js`. Now as I said there are a number of files in that folder and we want to generate this file at compile time with maven.

- Is there any way other than creating a maven plugin to do this?
- We are using EMAScript6

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There isn't a built-in way to do this, but a Browserify [Transform](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#browserifytransform) could handle the task. You could write one yourself, but I think [Bulkify](https://github.com/substack/bulkify) might do what you want already, depending on what format you want the result in.

See:

- [Bulkify](https://github.com/substack/bulkify)
- [bulk-require](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bulk-require)

Comment: That's what exactly we need. Thanks